# Laravel Blade Table Creation Nested Foreach Loops

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-7

First, I'm new to coding and Laravel in general, so go easy on me.

I need to display a table based on two Models:  Resources and Events.  I have created a one-to-many relationship between them.  Unfortunately for this table, I have special needs that the relationship simply isn't helping with.  The Event model keeps track of (among other things), the Checkout and Checkin time of each resource. (one Resource can have many Events)  Basically, if the resource's ID is listed on an event row, then someone has it checked out for some period of time.  I need to show if the resource is available for check out or already out for the date/time the user of the site is viewing.

Models (to show relationship)

Resource.php

```php
class Resource extends Model
{
    /**
     * Define Relationships to other models.
     *
     */
    // The Event Model
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
    }

}
```

Event.php

```php
class Event extends Model
{
    /**
     * Define Relationships to other models.
     *
     */
    // To the User Model
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    // To the Resource Model
    public function resource()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Resource');
    }
}
```

In the controller, I pull all the events that apply to the date like this:

```php
$formStartOfDay = Carbon::parse($formDate)->startOfDay();
$formEndOfDay = Carbon::parse($formDate)->endOfDay();

$caseOne = Event::whereDate('outTime', '>=', $formStartOfDay)
    ->whereDate('inTime', '<=', $formEndOfDay);

$caseTwo = Event::whereDate('outTime', '=', $formStartOfDay)
    ->whereDate('inTime', '>', $formEndOfDay);

$caseThree = Event::whereDate('outTime', '<', $formStartOfDay)
    ->whereDate('inTime', '=', $formEndOfDay);

$caseFour = Event::whereDate('outTime', '<', $formStartOfDay)
    ->whereDate('inTime', '>', $formEndOfDay);

$events = $caseOne->union($caseTwo)
    ->union($caseThree)
    ->union($caseFour)
    ->orderBy('outTime')
    ->get();
```

At the same time, I pull all the resources I need:

```php
$resources = Resource::whereIn('type', ['SUV', 'Truck', 'Car'])->get()->sortby('name');
```

With that passed to the view, I try to create the table I want.  A table that lists every resource whether it's checked out or not.  Those resources that are out will display "checked out" and list who has that resource.  A resource may be checked out more than once a day and needs to display all instances if it's out.

```php
    <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th scope="col">Vehicle</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Checked Out To</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($resources as $resource)
        @foreach ($events as $resource_event)
        @if ($resource_event['resource_id'] == $resource->id)
        <tr class="table-default" id="{{ $resource->id }}">
            @if ($loop->first)
            <td rowspan="{{ count($events->where('resource_id', $resource->id)) }}">
                {{ $resource->name }}
            </td>
            <td>{{ $resource->description }}</td>
            @endif
            @if ($resource_event->inOrOut($resource_event->outTime,
            $resource_event->inTime) === "Out" )
            <td class="text-center">Checked Out</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $resource_event->user->name }}</td>
            @else
            <td class="text-center">Available</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            @endif
        </tr>
        @else
        <tr class="table-default" id="{{ $resource->id }}">
            <td>{{ $resource->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $resource->description }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">Available</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        @endif
        @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With the blade code above, I'm getting multiple instances of each resource (one for each $event) and the rowspan simply freaks out when it's supposed to work.  I've tried various things and none of them give me what I want.  I've searched here, on Google, Laracasts and no situation is exactly like mine or has helped me solve the problem.  Hoping someone here can help me.

My intent for the ROWSPAN is so that the table (when working properly) will look like this:

```
========================================================
| Vehicle | Description | Status      | Checked Out To |
|------------------------------------------------------|
| Truck 1 | 4x4 Truck   | Available   |                |
|------------------------------------------------------|
| Truck 2 | 4x4 Truck   | Checked Out | Person 1       |
|         |             |------------------------------|
|         |             | Checked Out | Person 2       |
|------------------------------------------------------|
| Truck 3 | 2WD Truck   | Available   |                |
========================================================
```

Comment: I don't see no sign of laravel relationship feature used here.

Comment: Also, why you do intend to use rowspan? Is it not that you want add every event to it's own row? using a rowspan just doesn't sound so valid and legit.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi, you're right, the relationship isn't being for this table because I can't figure out a way that it can be used in a helpful manner.  (The relationship is being used in other parts of the application.)  If there is a way it can be used here, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

While there may be better ways of doing this, the solution I came up with is:

First, use Eager Loading with constraints to grab the combined data I needed from the database in the controller.

```php
// Establish the earliest and latest times of the form's date
$formStartOfDay = Carbon::parse($formDate)->startOfDay();
$formEndOfDay = Carbon::parse($formDate)->endOfDay();

// Gather needed data from the database.
// Get the data via Eager Loading
$resources = Resource::whereIn('type', ['SUV', 'Truck', 'Car'])->orderBy('name') 
    ->with(['events' => function ($query) use ($formStartOfDay, $formEndOfDay) {
        $query->whereDate('outTime', '>=', $formStartOfDay)->whereDate('inTime', '<=', $formEndOfDay)
        ->orWhereDate('outTime', '=', $formStartOfDay)->whereDate('inTime', '>', $formEndOfDay)
        ->orWhereDate('outTime', '<', $formStartOfDay)->whereDate('inTime', '=', $formEndOfDay)
        ->orWhereDate('outTime', '<', $formStartOfDay)->whereDate('inTime', '>', $formEndOfDay)
        ->orderBy('outTime');
    }])->get();
```

Next I modified the Blade template to use the new collection:

```php
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th scope="col">Vehicle</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Checked Out To</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 9%">Returning</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($resources as $resource)
        @if ($resource->events->contains('resource_id', $resource->id))
        @foreach ($resource->events as $resource_event)
        <tr class="table-default" id="{{ $resource->id }}">
            <td>{{ $resource->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $resource->description }}</td>
            @if ($resource_event->inOrOut($resource_event->outTime, $resource_event->inTime) === "Out" )
            <td class="text-center">Checked Out</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                {{ $resource_event->user->name }}<br />
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($resource_event->inTime)->format('m/d/Y g:i A') }}
            </td>
            @else
            <td class="text-center">Available</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            @endif
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        @else
        <tr class="table-default" id="{{ $resource->id }}">
            <td>{{ $resource->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $resource->description }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">Available</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The key to the solution was eager loading with the proper constraints.  That way I received all the "Resources" but only the "Events" I needed.  This allowed me to vastly simplify the Blade code and keep me out of very complicated loops and if-else blocks.

I hope this helps someone else in the future.